# Firestore FieldValue.arrayUnion not working in a Cloud Function

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to use the arrayUnion functionality of Firestore to add items to an Array.
I have a web application and the code below works fine and the elements are added to MyArray :

```
firebase.firestore().collection("MyCollection").doc("MyDocument").update({
     MyArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({element1: "qqq", element2: "www"})
});
```

But when I try to make it working in a cloud function, the code doesn't do anything. Nothing is written in my Firestore Array and there is no error on the cloud function logs.

Initialization :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

My cloud function has an HTTP trigger that works fine. The code in the cloud function is :

```
admin.firestore().collection("MyCollection").doc("MyDocument").update({
     MyArray: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({element1: "qqq", element2: "www"})
});
```

The same code with a simple element added, in the same HTTP triggered cloud function works fine :

```
admin.firestore().collection("MyCollection").doc("MyDocument").update({
     element1: "qqq"
});
```

It seems that admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion doesn't do anything.

The complete cloud function is deployed fine :

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   admin.firestore().collection("MyCollection").doc("MyDocument").update({

       MyArray: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({element1: "qqq", element2: "www"})

   });
   res.status(200).end();
});
```

He is my package.json file, all packages are up to date :

```
{
   "name": "functions",
   "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
   "scripts": {
   "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
   "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
   "start": "npm run shell",
   "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
   "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"dependencies": {
   "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.7.0",
   "admin": "^1.4.0",
   "firebase": "^5.5.9",
   "firebase-admin": "^6.2.0",
   "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
   "firestore": "^1.1.6",
},
"private": true
}
```

Am I missing something ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Where's your function trigger?  You can't just deploy code to Cloud Functions and run it as if it's a script.  You need to define a trigger that gets invoked when some conditions are met.

Comment: It's an HTTP trigger, and it works fine.

Comment: It always helps to see the *complete, minimal* code that reproduces the problem.  You might be doing something else wrong.  Also check the log to see if anything shows up there.

Comment: @ Doug, I have added the entire function, thanks.

Comment: @Fox5150 You should send the response only when the Promise returned by `update()` has resolved, i.e. in a `then()` function. Have a look at this video from... Doug :-) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3)

Comment: The function is going to terminate and clean up when you send a response.  Since you're sending the response *before* the async call to update completes, you have no guarantee that the async work will complete.  Take some time to learn about how Cloud Functions works with respect to async work.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Renaud and Doug, it works fine with a Promise :

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

return admin.firestore().collection("MyCollection").doc("MyDocument").update({

    MyArray: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        element1: "qqq",
        element2: "www"
    })

   }).then(() => {
    console.log('Write succeeded!');
    res.status(200).end();
   });

});
```

The function clean up was killing everything, and I did not thought that sending the status 200 was cleaning all the process. But one thing is strange : updating only one element is working fine without a promise, but updating the Array is not working ... This is certainly due to the execution time of a more complex process : the update of an Array...